# iOS 5 reminders for Mac

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, ios, reminders

I like iOS5 reminders app and use it on my iPod touch , however I am looking for an app for OSX lion which provide similar functionality for macOSX in an app which can sync with reminders app for iOS5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reminders on your iOS 5 device get synced automatically thorugh iCloud with the reminders in iCal.

Answer (score 2):

I use [WunderList](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist/) (free) on multiple devices iPhone, Macs, Android, Windows, and I share some lists with my friends.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality will be part of OS 10.8 Mountain Lion. 
[Here is the Macworld write up about it.](http://www.macworld.com/article/1165410/mountain_lion_hands_on_with_notes_and_reminders.html)

Answer (score -1):

I did a search in the Apple app store for "Reminders" and and app called "To-do Lists" came up. It looks like what you're looking for.